# Why with MSVC it works and with GNU come the error: array type has incomplete element type using struct

Tags: c

This is a small part of my program that runs on visual studio, gcc and another compiler. The the try to compile the code below I get from my gcc compiler the following following error:

```
In file included from myData.h:5:0,
                 from main.c:2:
def.h:14:39: error: array type has incomplete element type
   extern CONST_MACRO_DEF( struct foo, myData[] );
                                   ^
def.h:10:63: note: in definition of macro 'CONST_MACRO_DEF'
   #define CONST_MACRO_DEF( arg_type, arg_name) const arg_type arg_name __attribute__((section(".INFO")))
```

File macro.h

```
#ifndef MACRO_H_
#define MACRO_H_

#include <stdio.h>


#if defined (_MSC_VER)
   #pragma section(".INFO")
   #define CONST_MACRO_DEF( arg_type, arg_name) const arg_type __declspec(allocate(".INFO")) arg_name
#elif defined( __GNUC__ )    
   #define CONST_MACRO_DEF( arg_type, arg_name) const arg_type arg_name __attribute__((section(".INFO")))
#else
   #define CONST_MACRO_DEF( arg_type, arg_name) const arg_type arg_name 
#endif

struct foo;

extern CONST_MACRO_DEF( struct foo, myData[] );

#endif /* MACRO_H_ */
```

File myData.h

```
#ifndef MY_DATA_H_
#define MY_DATA_H_

#include "def.h"

struct foo
{
   int    nummer;
   double myHight;
};


CONST_MACRO_DEF( struct foo, myData[] ) = 
{
   { 1 , 5.5 },
   { 2 , 6.0 },
   { 3 , 7.9 }
};

#endif
```

File main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myData.h"

int main(void)
{

    return 0;
}
```

Remarks:

- The the real code is been successfully compiled with visual studio, but not with GCC compiler.
- It is possible to compile the code with gcc if i change my struct foo in macro.h from incomplete type to complete type, by moving the definition of it from myData.h and placing it in def.h. (I would prefer a solution which will remain struct foo in macro.h an incomplete type)

Comment: You can't do that because the size of the struct is unknown to the compiler, you should include the `struct` definition in the file where you mean to initialize it, if you want to make it static, otherwise you can always use pointers.

Comment: @iharob why does the compiler need to know the size?

Comment: @Jansen, if the compiler doesn't know the size how can it do the initialization, the definition must be in the same compilation unit as the initialization. Not necessarily in the same file, but sure in the same compilation unit.

Comment: a reference to the struct only works when the struct definition is already available.  a simple fix.  #include <def.h> after the struct definition rather than before the struct definition

Comment: @user3629249, your solution worked, but i would probably get a Lint error of including file not at the header.

Comment: @iharob, i tried using points, but without success. could you supply an example?

Comment: You can reference a `struct` whose members are not yet declared.  Such a `struct` is, at that point, an "incomplete type".  That's useful for some purposes, but there are many things you cannot do with an incomplete type -- basically anything that requires knowing its size of accessing storage through it.

Comment: @iharob,  yeah, for some reason there's initialisation in the .h file. I didn't notice that.

Comment: I can's see any way that mydata.h will produce anything but a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is probably in the handling of **declspec(allocate(".INFO")) and __attribute**((section(".INFO"))).

Now this things are explicitly non-standard. You should probably check MSVC and GCC docs.

Concerning gcc section attribute should be used on variables, not extern declaration hence the error related to incomplete type.

Comment: I use unable to find in GNU something that does not allow __attribute(section(....)). In addition i found that GNU does allow it with functions in http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/2361001/ (still not contredition to what you wrote)

Comment: Oh, I was wrong (did some experiments with gcc, don't have access to MSVC though)! Please confirm that if you change myData declaration in macro.h to extern CONST_MACRO_DEF( struct foo, myData[__3__] ); it doesn't compile in MSVC as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pointers you can use a forward declaration like this

```
struct foo;
```

and then you can have this kind of declaration

```
struct foo *somefoo;
```

but if you don't include the `struct` definition you will not be allowed to access the members of the `struct`.

That is actually a technique not hide the members from the user, it's called `opaque struct` and it's very useful since there is no `private` keyword in c, it could help hiding the definition to avoid stupid things araising from directly changing the members of the `struct`.

If you don't include the structure definition in any way you like, **you will not be able to access it's members** and since it's size would be unknown you will not be able to declare a static instance of it.